# AWS Amplfy withAuthenticator hide "Sign up" option in index.js page

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

Anyone has any idea, how to hide the create account button in the login page of amplify? following is my index.js page, and i tried many solution to try and hide the create account button, but it doesnt work.

I am using the HOC components withAuthenticator. I am using the HOC components withAuthenticator, but i try hiding the create account link, it does not work. I had tried many others solutions.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
    import Teacherpage from './Teacher/Teacherpage';
    import Studentpage from './Child/Childpage';
    import Guardianpage from './Guardian/Guardianpage';
    import SchoolAdminpage from './SchoolAdmin/SchoolAdminpage';
    import CCACoachPage from './CCACoach/CCACoachpage';
    import awsExports from '../src/aws-exports';
    import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';

    Amplify.configure(awsExports);

    const index = () => {
      const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        checkUserProfile();
      }, []);

      const checkUserProfile = async () => {
        try {
          const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
          const { attributes } = userInfo;
          const userProfile = attributes.profile;
          //console.log(userProfile)
          setUserProfile(userProfile);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getting user profile:', error);
        }
      };

      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
          {
          
          userProfile === 'Form Teacher' ? (
            <Teacherpage />
        ) : userProfile === 'Teacher' ? (
            <Teacherpage />
          ) : userProfile === 'Student' ? (
            <Studentpage />
          ) :  userProfile === 'Guardian' ? (
            <Guardianpage />
          ):  userProfile === 'schooladmin' ? (
            <SchoolAdminpage />
          ):  userProfile === 'CCA Teacher' ? (
            <CCACoachPage />
          ):
            <Text>no profile found</Text>

          }
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        //flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        padding: 100,
      },
      main: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        maxWidth: 960,
        marginHorizontal: "auto",
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 64,
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },
      subtitle: {
        fontSize: 36,
        color: "#38434D",
      },
    });

  

    export default withAuthenticator(index, { hideSignUp: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a components object to customize the SignIn view:

```
import {
  Authenticator
  withAuthenticator,
} from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';


export default withAuthenticator(index, {
  components: {
    SignIn: (props) => <Authenticator.SignIn {...props} hideSignUp />,
  },
});
```